# the issue is probably caused by a circular import

Tags: django, python-3.x

i'm trying to runserver for a django project and it shows me this error : 
The included URLconf 'Smartfarmer.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

eventhough the same project works fine in another envirenement

i've tried to check if there are any mistakes in urls but i believe everything is fine

my urls file of the project :
smartfarmer.urls:

```py
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from main_app import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^',
        include('main_app.urls')),
     url(r'^detect/',
        include('detect.urls')),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my urls for my apps :

main_app.urls:

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index),
]
```

detect.urls:

```py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^result/$', views.result, name='result'),
]
```

Comment: set `namespace` for your includes

Comment: Which one is smartfarmer.urls?

Comment: @katoozi how can you do it please ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman the first one !

Comment: can you say 2 last `urls.py` belong to which apps.

Comment: @katoozi i've edited the post you can check now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## First way:

smartfarmer.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('main_app.urls', namespace="main")),
    url(r'^detect/', include('detect.urls', namespace="detect")),
]
```

main_app.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

## Second way:

main_app.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "main"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name="index"),
]
```

detect.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = "detect"
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^result/$', views.result, name='result'),
]
```